# Make a square multiplication table in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I got this question in an interview and got almost all the way to the answer but got stuck on the last part. If I want to get the multiplication table for 5, for instance, I want to get the output to be formatted like so:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
2, 4, 6, 8, 10
3, 6, 9, 12, 15
4, 8, 12, 16, 20
5, 10, 15, 20, 25
```

My answer to this is:

```
def make_table(n)
  s = ""
  1.upto(n).each do |i|
    1.upto(n).each do |j|
      s += (i*j).to_s
    end
    s += "\n"
  end
  p s
end
```

But the output for make_table(5) is:

```
"12345\n246810\n3691215\n48121620\n510152025\n"
```

I've tried variations with array but I'm getting similar output.

What am I missing or how should I think about the last part of the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use map and join to get a String in one line :

```
n = 5 
puts (1..n).map { |x| (1..n).map { |y| x * y }.join(', ') }.join("\n")
```

It iterates over rows (x=1, x=2, ...). For each row, it iterates over cells (y=1, y=2, ...) and calculates `x*y`. It joins every cells in a row with `,`, and joins every rows in the table with a newline :

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
2, 4, 6, 8, 10
3, 6, 9, 12, 15
4, 8, 12, 16, 20
5, 10, 15, 20, 25
```

If you want to keep the commas aligned, you can use rjust :

```
puts (1..n).map { |x| (1..n).map { |y| (x * y).to_s.rjust(3) }.join(',') }.join("\n")
```

It outputs :

```
  1,  2,  3,  4,  5
  2,  4,  6,  8, 10
  3,  6,  9, 12, 15
  4,  8, 12, 16, 20
  5, 10, 15, 20, 25
```

You could even go fancy and calculate the width of `n**2` before aligning commas :

```
n = 11
width = Math.log10(n**2).ceil + 1
puts (1..n).map { |x| (1..n).map { |y| (x * y).to_s.rjust(width) }.join(',') }.join("\n")
```

It outputs :

```
   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10,  11
   2,   4,   6,   8,  10,  12,  14,  16,  18,  20,  22
   3,   6,   9,  12,  15,  18,  21,  24,  27,  30,  33
   4,   8,  12,  16,  20,  24,  28,  32,  36,  40,  44
   5,  10,  15,  20,  25,  30,  35,  40,  45,  50,  55
   6,  12,  18,  24,  30,  36,  42,  48,  54,  60,  66
   7,  14,  21,  28,  35,  42,  49,  56,  63,  70,  77
   8,  16,  24,  32,  40,  48,  56,  64,  72,  80,  88
   9,  18,  27,  36,  45,  54,  63,  72,  81,  90,  99
  10,  20,  30,  40,  50,  60,  70,  80,  90, 100, 110
  11,  22,  33,  44,  55,  66,  77,  88,  99, 110, 121
```

Comment: ...or `(1..n).each { |x| puts (1..n).map { |y| x * y }.join(', ') }`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Sure, it depends if you just want to display a table or get a String. The method in the question actually did both.

Comment: True, but it's hard to imagine what use such a string would have. Oh, well. Also, consider `width = n.to_s.size + 1`. :-)

Comment: Ah, yes. If you're formatting the table there's even less of a need for the commas.

Answer (score 2):

Without spaces between the figures, the result is indeed unreadable. Have a look at the % operator, which formats strings and numbers. Instead of

```
s += (i*j).to_s
```

you could write

```
s += '%3d' % (i*j)
```

If you really want to get the output formatted in the way you explained in your posting (which **I** don't find that much readable), you could do a

```
s += "#{i*j}, "
```

This leaves you with two extra characters at the end of the line, which you have to remove. An alternative would be to use an array. Instead of the inner loop, you would have then something like

```
s += 1.upto(n).to_a.map {|j| i*j}.join(', ') + "\n"
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to construct a string if you're only interested in printing the table and not returning the table(as a string).

```
(1..n).each do |a|
  (1..n-1).each { |b| print "#{a * b}, " }
  puts a * n
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'd do it.

```
require 'matrix'

n = 5

puts Matrix.build(n) { |i,j| (i+1)*(j+1) }.to_a.map { |row| row.join(', ') }
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
2, 4, 6, 8, 10
3, 6, 9, 12, 15
4, 8, 12, 16, 20
5, 10, 15, 20, 25
```

See [Matrix::build](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-c-build).

Answer (score 0):

You can make it much shorter but here's my version.

```
range = Array(1..12)
range.each do |element|
  range.map { |item| print "#{element * item} " } && puts
end
```